# How should this pandas dataframe be setup to support these operations?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Need to be able to do simple aggregates that represent responses to a set of questions on a form. What would be the best way to store this data in a pandas dataframe?

## Data Model

I have a set of responses that come from questions on a page, the responses are 1D, 2D, and
3D representations:

### 1D

In 1 dimensional you can only select a row:

What is your favorite color?
- ( ) Blue
- ( ) Orange
- ( ) Green

### 2D

In 2 dimensional you can select a row and a column:

Rank these foods:

```
|       | Poor  |    OK  | Good  |  Great  |
|-------|-------|--------|-------|---------|
|Mexican| X     |        |       |         |
|Italian|       |        |   X   |         |
|Chinese|       |        |       |    X    |
```

### 3D

In 3 dimensional you can select a row, a column, and a choice:

Rank these vehicles:

```
|       | Speed       | Safety     |
|-------|-------------|------------|
|Chevy  | [Fast, Slow]| [Good, Bad]|
|Ford   | [Fast, Slow]| [Good, Bad]|
|BMW    | [Fast, Slow]| [Good, Bad]|
```

### Attributes

Outside of the answers to their questions there are other attributes that are tracked like:

- User agent (Chrome, Firefox, IE)
- Geo Location (Canada, USA, China)
- Operating System (Windows, Linux, OSX, iOS)

## Expected results

### Basic questions

Questions that I may want to ask this data:

- How many people answered a row in a 1D question
- How many people answered a row/column pair in a 2D question
- How many people answered a row/column/choice pair in a 3D question
- Compare responses by which browser brought in those responses
- Compare responses by which country brought in those responses

### Example response

## 1D

Give counts by row:

```
{
    "question": {
       "form_id": 1,
       "question_id": 1234,
       "text": "What is your favorite color?"
    },
    "total": 20,
    "row_headers": [
        {"id": "123", "label": "blue"},
        {"id": "456", "label": "orange"},
        {"id": "789", "label": "green"},
    ],
    "counts": [
        {"row_id": "456", "total": 5, "percentage": 25},
        {"row_id": "789", "total": 5, "percentage": 25},
        {"row_id": "123", "total": 5, "percentage": 25},
        {"row_id": "123", "total": 5, "percentage": 25},
    ],
}
```

## 2D

Give counts by row/column:

```
{
    "question": {
       "form_id": 1,
       "question_id": 4567,
       "text": "Rank these foods?"
    },
    "total": 20,
    "row_headers": [
        {"id": "123", "label": "Chevy"},
        {"id": "456", "label": "Ford"},
        {"id": "789", "label": "BMW"},
    ],
    "column_headers": [
        {"id": "321", "label": "Speed"},
        {"id": "654", "label": "Safety"},
    ],
    "counts": [
        {"row_id": "456", "col_id": "321" "total": 10, "percentage": 50},
        {"row_id": "789", "col_id": "654" "total": 10, "percentage": 50},
    ],
}
```

## Attributes

Give counts of 1D question by Browser, this would basically turn a 1D question into a 2D response:

```
{
    "question": {
       "form_id": 1,
       "question_id": 4567,
       "text": "Rank these foods?"
    },
    "total": 20,
    "row_headers": [
        {"id": "444", "label": "Chrome"},
        {"id": "555", "label": "Firefox"},
        {"id": "666", "label": "IE"},
    ],
    "column_headers": [
        {"id": "123", "label": "blue"},
        {"id": "456", "label": "orange"},
        {"id": "789", "label": "green"},
    ],
    "counts": [
        {"row_id": "444", "col_id": "123" "total": 10, "percentage": 50},
        {"row_id": "555", "col_id": "789" "total": 10, "percentage": 50},
    ],
}
```

## Help

- How would you design your pandas DataFrame to allow this type of processing easily?
- Do you think the response data structure I described makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the right way to organize a DataFrame for analysis is in the form of [Tidy Data](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v59/i10/paper). You should read the paper, but here's the punchline:

1. Each variable forms a column.
2. Each observation forms a row.

It's up to you exactly what counts as an "observation", but I would think that in your case each survey question would be one or more variables, e.g., "favorite_color", "mexican_rank", "italian_rank", etc.

Once you have your data in tidy form, most of your analysis questions reduce to easy groupby operations, e.g., `df.groupby('operating_system')['favorite_color'].mean()`.